# How can I stop "propagation" on this scenario?

Tags: jquery, handler, stoppropagation

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/pkhJQ/) :

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="link">Link</div>
</div>​

$('#link').click(function (e) {
    console.log("link");                
});

$('#container').mousedown(function (e) {
    console.log("container");                
});
```

I'd like that, when I click on `#link`, it will not fire the `#container` handler. Tried `stopPropagation()` or `preventDefault()`, but I think it is the wrong approch?

Comment: e.preventDefault() should work.

Comment: no : http://jsfiddle.net/pkhJQ/1/

Comment: `mousedown` fires before the click event of course.

Answer (score 2):

The `mousedown` handler fires before the `click` handler, hence you can't cancel the `mousedown` handler from the `click` handler as the `mousedown` event already bubbled up to the parent element.

Without modifying your other handlers, I'd simply add a `mousedown` handler to the inner element to stop the `mousedown` event propagation.

```
$('#link').click(function (e) {
    console.log("link");
}).mousedown(function (e) { //stops the mousedown event propagation from reaching
    e.stopPropagation();   //the parent element
});

$('#container').mousedown(function (e) {
    console.log("container");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pkhJQ/3/)

If you are able to switch the handlers to handle the same event (e.g. both `click`), you will be able to call [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) from the inner element's handler as I did with the `mousedown` handlers above.

Answer (score 0):

According to these questions/answers:

[Prevent parent container click event from firing when hyperlink clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997084/prevent-parent-container-click-event-from-firing-when-hyperlink-clicked)

[How to prevent trigger container's event when trigger children's events in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633086/how-to-prevent-trigger-containers-event-when-trigger-childrens-events-in-jquer)

`e.stopPropagation();` is the correct way to go.

http://jsfiddle.net/MN5KK/1/

Edit:
I see you're using `mousedown` on the container and `click` on the link, the mouse down event will always fire before the click because click is on release.